# Restkit is not able to map keys containing dots

Tags: objective-c, restkit

I tried following this tutorial [RKGist Tutorial](https://github.com/RestKit/RKGist/blob/master/TUTORIAL.md) which is not yet complete. I managed to map the users correctly, but I have problems with the files.

The json is like this (while '...' stands for left out stuff):

```
[
  {
    "url": "gist.gisthub.com",
    "id": "11111",
    ...
    "files": {
      "gistfile1.phtml": {
        "filename": "gistfile1.phtml",
        "raw_url": "some_url"
        "size": 126
        ...
      }
      "file2.test": {
        "filename": "file2.test",
        "raw_url": "some_url"
        "size": 126
        ...
      }
    },
    "user": { 
      ...
    },
  }
]
```

My File object looks like this.

```
@interface RKGFile : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * filename;
@property (nonatomic, retain) id rawURL;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * size;
@property (nonatomic, retain) RKGGist *gist;

@end
```

And My mapping (only the part for the files, the rest works)

```
RKEntityMapping* fileMapping =  [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"File" inManagedObjectStore:managedObjectStore];
fileMapping.forceCollectionMapping = YES; 

// Define nested attribute 
[fileMapping addAttributeMappingFromKeyOfRepresentationToAttribute:@"filename"];
[fileMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
                                              @"(filename).raw_url": @"rawURL",
                                              @"(filename).size": @"size"
                                              }];


[gistMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"files" toKeyPath:@"files" withMapping:fileMapping]];
```

This mapping gets the filenames correctly, but the nesting attribute e.g. '(filename).raw_url' does not match at all, size and rawURL are both always nil.

As far as I can see, this is similar to the usecase in the docs [Dynamic Nested Attributes](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Object-Mapping#handling-dynamic-nesting-attributes) but somehow only the dynamic attribute (filename) gets mapped, not the nested attributes as well.

The problem is that the key "gistfile1.phtml" contains a dot which makes the mapping look for a nested object 'phtml' within 'gistfile1' instead of directly using this as a key.

Does anyone know a way around this? 
This is pretty limiting.
Thanks for helping :)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like an open bug in RestKit https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/issues/1532